# redirect all pages of a site to an other file

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I need to redirect all pages of a domain, except two of them, to a given url.
the problem is, that i dont know how to redirect only the pages from the curent directory and subdirectories, and not the images, css, and js files too.
Hope I wasnt too confusing:)
thanks for all the answers.
Zoli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/(page1.htm|page2.htm)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|gif|jpeg) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somewhere.org/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Explanation
1st line - ignore the pages you want
2nd line - ignore the resources you want
3rd line redirect everything else

Comment: Can you please tell me how to include a list of directories to the ignored list (like the page1.htm and page2.htm)?